# argument of type 'instancemethod' is not iterable

Tags: python, django

Multiple check box in html, if `None` selected i want my user redirect to the same page.

Shall i do this via Javascript ? Or

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'trackid' in request.POST.getlist and request.POST.getlist('trackid')!= "":
            new_check = request.POST.getlist('trackid')
        else:
            return redirect('app:frontview')
```

Oh.. i am getting this error `argument of type 'instancemethod' is not iterable`

Comment: The second condition in the second line will never be false. `getlist` returns a list, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check membership of the key in the [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict), not in the method of the QueryDict.

The following line:

```
'trackid' in request.POST.getlist
```

should be replaced with:

```
'trackid' in request.POST
```